# Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath

Tags: java, android

**GRADLE SYNC FAILED WITH AN ERROR**

[image: ERROR]

**app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
 //   buildToolsVersion "26.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.eilabpc.pragati"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am also using a proxy. I have made sure that the android studio is connected to the internet. I have tied to disable offile 
I am also using a proxy. I have made sure that the android studio is connected to the internet. I have tied to disable offile I am also using a proxy. I have made sure that the android studio is connected to the internet. I have tied to disable offile I am also using a proxy. I have made sure that the android studio is connected to the internet. I have tied to disable offile I am also using a proxy. I have made sure that the android studio is connected to the internet. I have tied to disable offile I am also using a proxy. I have made sure that the android studio is connected to the internet. I have tied to disable offile I am also using a proxy. I have made sure that the android studio is connected to the internet. I have tied to disable offile I am also using a proxy. I have made sure that the android studio is connected to the internet. I have tied to disable offile

Comment: Remove the proxy and if you are under firewall get the access from the IT manager. and Resync the gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Remove both lines it will work.

`androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'`

`androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'`